# Azure Vs AWS VM storage costs

Tags: azure, azure-app-service-plans

I am trying to price out moving our company to azure or aws. I recently created a Azure VM at $45 a month.

2 Core +
4GB Ram +
8GB Temporary storage

I choose a HDD unmanaged disk when creating the VM. When I remote into the VM i see a 8GB D drive but I also see a 120GB C drive. What is the cost of the C drive?

Also how does this compare AWS, do they charge extra for this 120gb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

D drive is temporary and a free one (its not persistent). Its size depends on the VM SKU.
C drive is persistent and costs money. You can use Azure calculator to find out the cost (https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/pricing/calculator/)

Comment: Once you use the C drive is it now considered a managed disk?

Comment: no, managed\unmanaged is a completely different story. check this: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/virtual-machines/windows/managed-disks-overview

Comment: alright, so the you pay as you go on the 120gb C drive?

Comment: yeah, you pay for that 127gb drive, i think its about couple of $\month